# Gulp installs outside project root

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp, node-modules

I've encountered a weird issue when installing Gulp in a new project.

Let's say I have the following path:

```
c:/development/myproject
```

When I run `npm install gulp` in that directory, the node_modules folder actually gets created in

```
c:/development/node_modules
```

instead of

```
c:/development/myproject/node_modules
```

And all of gulp plugins also get installed in that directory outside my project root.

I also have an earlier project where gulp was already installed before, and when I tried to rerun gulp installation in that project directory it was installed correctly in the project root (for example: `c:/development/myolderproject/node_modules`), not outside.

I don't think it has anything to do with the case, but the new project is using Laravel 4, while the other one is on Laravel 5.

I don't recall having to set any specific configuration before, so I'm totally confused why it behaves differently.

Comment: Can you check if there's package.json in `c:/development` or `c:/development/myproject`?

Comment: Indeed there was in `c:/development`. After deleting it and creating a blank one in project folder gulp now installs in project root. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `npm install` it found `package.json` from parent directory and thought it was the package root.

Related docs: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html#more-information

> Starting at the $PWD, npm will walk up the folder tree checking for a folder that contains either a package.json file, or a node_modules folder. If such a thing is found, then that is treated as the effective "current directory" for the purpose of running npm commands. (This behavior is inspired by and similar to git's .git-folder seeking logic when running git commands in a working dir.)
>
> If no package root is found, then the current folder is used.

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu 15 and I had a similar issue where gulp was installing the node_module folder somewhere I couldn't find. gulp would say ../../node_modules was the location but it was NOT in my project folder.

I figured out from the link above and some more research I just needed to run npm init to create a project.json in my project folder. gulp was installing the node_modules in another folder because it searches for a project.json file to install the folder node_modules into.

Hope this helps anyone else solve this silly problem.